# How to implement filter in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a Webpage here I am Displaying My Product details, in this page and I want the following requirements

```
Display products should have filtering options:
         a. From lower to higher price
         b. From Higher to lower price
         c. Newly created 
         d. Alphabetical order
```

I would like to know how to implement the above requirements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CodeIgniter Shopping Cart</title>

<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/core.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/core1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="cart_data">
           <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart1/show_cart">View Cart </a>
    <div id="cart_message"> </div>
<div id="wrap">

    <?php $this->view('products1'); ?>
    <!--
    <div class="cart_list">
        <h3>Your shopping cart</h3>
        <div id="cart_content">
            <?php //echo $this->view('cart1.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>-->

</div>
   <!-- <p style="text-align: justify;"><div id="pagination"> <?php //echo $links; ?> </div></p>-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to do sorting on client side, then juqery datatable is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

you don't say that the products are stored in a database or not.  If they are not, they probably should be.

then if your products are stored in a database, it is simple to order them using the $this->db->order_by('field_name desc|asc');   note you have not asked to 'filter' you have asked to 'order'

so, read about the documentation about the MVC approach that codeigniter uses.  make a products model that will handle creating the products table, adding, deleting, and fetching the products, along with the ordering you need.  make a controller to coordinate these tasks, and create views to display the data.

think of the things you want the product table to do, and work out what you need to store to make that happen -- so from what you describe, the products table needs something like:

```
    create table products (
      id int unsigned auto_increment,
      name varchar(255) not null,
      price float unsigned not null,
    primary key (id))
    ENGINE=InnoDB default CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

then you can get the results as an array of objects with something like:

```
function get_records($order_by)
{
  return $this->db->from('products')
     ->order_by($order_by)
     ->get()
     ->result();
}
```

where order by is

a:  price asc

b: price desc

c: id desc

d: name asc